# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (500, 4) but got array with shape (4, 2)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

How to Fix this error? I tried visiting all the forums searching for answers to rectify this issue.

Here i am trying to perform multi-label classification using keras

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint

MAX_LENGTH = 500
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df.overview.values)
post_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df.overview.values)
post_seq_padded = pad_sequences(post_seq, maxlen=MAX_LENGTH)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(post_seq_padded, train_encoded, test_size=0.3)
vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1
inputs = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH, ))
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 128, input_length=MAX_LENGTH)(inputs)
x = Dense(64, input_shape=(None,), activation='relu')(embedding_layer)
predictions = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=predictions)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()

filepath="weights.hdf5"
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
history = model.fit(X_train, batch_size=64, y=to_categorical(y_train), verbose=1, validation_split=0.25, shuffle=True, epochs=10, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

**ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)**

```
<ipython-input-11-7fdc4bff9648> in <module>
 2 checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
3 history = model.fit(X_train, batch_size=64, y=to_categorical(y_train), verbose=1, validation_split=0.25,
**---->** 4 shuffle=True, epochs=10, callbacks=[checkpointer])
```

***ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (500, 4) but got array with shape (4, 2)***

I expected to have the output shape as (500,3) but i am getting (4,2) which is not matching to proceed further.

Comment: what is your `df` size ?

Comment: @Tiendung -   It has 200 Rows with 2 columns (Its an sample dataset ) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PB7xnodZpT7EFcKq8d6vBmIR9EuczqAm/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try flatten the output of embedding layers before passing it to the dense layer, like below:

```
embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 128, input_length=MAX_LENGTH)(inputs)
flat_layer = Flatten()(embedding_layer)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(flat_layer)
```

Comment: Still getting the Error :-- ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_17 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (111, 4, 2)

Comment: getting (500,4)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x = Dense(64, input_dim = 500, activation='relu')(embedding_layer)
```